# Drop-down list closes at unwanted time

Tags: javascript, html, css, typeahead

I want to create `search-input` with `drop-down list`. The list must close when i have focused or clicked anywhere except `search-input`.

I added `listClose()` to `"blur"-Listener`. But now I can`t catch click-event from drop-down elements. Which is the event-listener I really need? Or I need the another realization?

Please, run snippet below. I tried to write it the most clear.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var inputElement = document.getElementById("input_word-search");
  var listElement = document.getElementById("dd-menu_search-input");

  // Input will focused when document is ready.
  inputElement.focus();

  listOpen = function() {
    listElement.classList.add('dd-open');
  };

  listClose = function() {
    listElement.classList.remove('dd-open');
  };

  inputElement.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
    listOpen();
  });

  inputElement.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
    listClose();
  });
})
```

```css
.dd-menu {
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.dd-suggestion {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.dd-suggestion:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #697981;
}

.dd-open {
  display: block;
}

.dd-empty {
  display: none;
}

#dd-menu_search-input {
  width: 74%;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="input-group">
    <input id="input_word-search" class="input_search suggest__field" type="search" autocomplete="off" name="q" placeholder="Seach">
    <div id="dd-menu_search-input" class="dd-menu dd-open">
      <div class="dd-dataset">
        <div class="dd-suggestion" onclick="alert('Click!')">
          suggestion-1
        </div>
        <div class="dd-suggestion" onclick="alert('Click!')">
          suggestion-2
        </div>
        <div class="dd-suggestion" onclick="alert('Click!')">
          suggestion-3
        </div>
        <div class="dd-suggestion" onclick="alert('Click!')">
          suggestion-4
        </div>
        <div class="dd-suggestion" onclick="alert('Click!')">
          suggestion-5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: are there any `stopPropagation()` or `return false` in your code ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa There are not. And problem plays with the code that I provided.

Comment: I asked because I'm confused by the reason why `onmousedown` would work but `onclick` would not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added boolean-variable that indicates mousedown-event on `drop-down list`

```
    var mousedownOnNodeCalee = false;

    listElement.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        mousedownOnNodeCalee = true;
    });

    inputElement.addEventListener("blur", function (e) {
        if(!mousedownOnNodeCalee) {
            listClose();
            return;
        }
        inputElement.focus();
        mousedownOnNodeCalee = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution (or may I say workaround) is to use `onmousedown` instead of `onclick`, so it will look like this (Note that I'm also removing the `alert()` and using a `console.log()` instead)

```
<body>

  <div id="input-group">
    <input id="input_word-search" class="input_search suggest__field" type="search" autocomplete="off" name="q" placeholder="Seach">
    <div id="dd-menu_search-input" class="dd-menu dd-open">
      <div class="dd-dataset">
        <div class="dd-suggestion" onmousedown="console.log('Click!')">
          suggestion-1
        </div>
        <div class="dd-suggestion" onmousedown="console.log('Click!')">
          suggestion-2
        </div>
        <div class="dd-suggestion" onmousedown="console.log('Click!')">
          suggestion-3
        </div>
        <div class="dd-suggestion" onmousedown="console.log('Click!')">
          suggestion-4
        </div>
        <div class="dd-suggestion" onmousedown="console.log('Click!')">
          suggestion-5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, its working! Unfortunatly, its only workaround. Because dd-menu have padding. And dd-list will close when i clicked on this padding.

Comment: Please, tell me why `onmousedown` works and `onmouseclick` doesn't  work?

Comment: The `onmousedown` event is registered before the `blur` event, that's why it's working. The problem here is that your `blur` event closes the list so all `click` events of that list can't be triggered because the list is closed.

Are you forced to stick with the `blur` event approach?

Comment: I am not forced to stick with the `blur`. But `dd-menu` must be closed when user click or focus on another dom-element.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is when you focusout the textbox, it call `blur` function and the list immediately disapear. So you can't click on the list. You can walkaround by `setTimeout` to `listClose()` like this

```
listClose = function() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      listElement.classList.remove('dd-open');
    },100)
};
```